# Run custom validation only if all other wordpress registration form validation was successful

Tags: user-registration

I've successfully added a Stripe payment field to my WP registration form, and have successfully added it to registration_errors filter (i.e. the registration only goes through if the stripe charge was successful; if there was an error like card declined, the reg fails).

But the problem is, if there wasn't an error with stripe, but rather some other built in wordpress validation that failed such as a blank field or username already in use, then the stripe payment still goes through even though the actual reg doesn't.

So my question is, how can I make sure my stripe custom validation in registration_errors runs last only when all the other built in wordpress validation was successful?

Comment: change the priority on the `add_filter` line to 11 so it runs after the default filters which have a priority of 10. eg. `add_filter('registration_errors', 'custom_stripe_validation', 11);`

Comment: another option is to use the `register_post` filter which runs after that one